# Simultaneous read & write to file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

So my scenario is as follows:

I have a directory, and every X second a Java application polls the directory to see if any new files have been added. If a new file is detected (which may be transferred there by unknown FTP implementation), I want to have a look in the file to see if it ends with a specific string (i.e. "allData"). If the string exists, I will start to parse it for my needs since the file is considered to be successfully transferred.

So the problem is that the file being transferred may be really big (several GBs) and I don't want the parsing to start before the entire file has been completely transferred (which is indicated by the ending "allData" string). And when I want to have a look into the file for this string, the search has to be fast and low in memory consumption. Due to this reason I use a RandomAccessFile object (read only mode) which sets to file descriptor to quite near the end of the file, and then I start to search using that FD and a BufferedReader.

What my question is whether or not my file opening in the Java application will affect the file transfer being executed. Because it might be the case that the application starts to read (to decide whether or not the entire file has been transferred) before the file has been transferred. Will anything nasty happen in such an implementation?

Comment: Have you considered to write the file in one directory and only when the file write is complete to move it in your folder? The move operation should not be too expensive since the file remains the same and you don't have to deal with special end patterns which could lead to future bugs.

Comment: When do I know when it's complete? That's the core issue here. Besides, moving from different directories have the same issue as FTP.

Comment: Moving a file, in almost every OS means just changing a reference on the filesystem, so the operation is pretty fast even for large files. If you move files, the fact that a file _is_ in your directory means that the file is ready to process. I had the same issue once and that worked perfectly. Also renaming is a solution but imho using separate folders is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just let the remote end transfer the file using ftp, then make the remote end rename the file from "filename.file.incomplete" to "filename.file" , you could then poll for stuff that doesnt have the "incomplete" in the end.

Comment: and depending on your operating system and stuff, reading a file that is being written might have weird results.

Comment: This is my current solution (renaming the file which indicates that transfer is complete) but this extra interaction is something that I would like to avoid.

Comment: make the sending party rename it after the transfer is complete. a rename is a very fast operation.

Comment: Yes, but I guess that a rename would force the transfer to some kind of human interaction? Or is it possible to automate it via file transfer, that the file should be renamed?

Comment: depends on what software you are using to do the ftp transfer, but ftp has a command to "rename" and most simpler ftp clients support that command and they can be scripted.